# Loading Chart. Please Wait

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I am getting this error in the div that the fusion map is to be created in.  I am using just basic maps to load and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var salesMap = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'usa',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '600',
        height: '400',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
            }
        }
    }).render();
```

I am loading, fusioncharts.js, fusioncharts.charts.js, fusioncharts.maps.js, fusioncharts.powercharts.js, fusioncharts.widgets.js, fusioncharts/js/maps/fusioncharts.usa.js

If i remove the fusioncharts.usa.js, it will say "Chart type not supported."  That leads me to believe that it is recognizing that map definition and it is attempting to load it.  If I replace all of the fusionMaps code with a fusionChart simple bar graph, it works with no problem.  I also attempted to only run fusioncharts.js, fusioncharts.maps.js, and fusioncharts/js/maps/fusioncharts.usa.js and nothing worked.  I also tried to change the type: 'usa' to type: 'maps/usa', but that didn't change anything.  I am not sure what else to try, the above code works in jsfiddle just like the bar graph.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type:'usa' to type: 'fusioncharts/js/maps/usa'.